# GCP billing support needed - services stopped and yet still get charge

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

i am a bronze GCP user who ended the trial. I need guide on why i still get charges when my VM are not running, disable google cloud SQL service.

Screenshot here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uuWPfg8eXjZWry3QUprWTsk5LDPc-YiT

Thank you for your input

Comment: The image link is now public. i am not sure what to do and i removed my billing account LOL!

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure because your Google Drive link isn't publicly shared, but your charges could be due to the resources attached to your VM. From GCP's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance) on stopping an instance:

> Your instances are not charged for per-second usage charges in TERMINATED state but any resources attached to the virtual machine will be charged until they are deleted, such as static IPs and persistent disks.

[GCP billing support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) will likely be of more help to you in this case than Stack Overflow. Even if you don't have a premium support package you can still request a chat to resolve billing issues.

Comment: Definitely this: the top circle for "SSD backed PD capacity" is the charge for storing data on redundant SSDs. The persistent disk sticks around when the VM isn't running (it'd be terrible if it didn't!) and, for us-central at least, costs $0.17 per gigabyte per month